# C++- freeing dyncamically allocated memory for a member variable of a class gives error

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, malloc, free

I have a class like this:

```
Class Attributes
{
Public:
    float* data;
    float* x;
    float min_x;
    float max_x;
    ~Attributes();
};
```

at some point in the main function I create this:

```
Attributes attr;
float* data =(float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
float* x =(float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
/* populate values of data and x */

attr.data = data;
attr.x = x;
```

Then I populate the values and do my operation.

Now I understand that since I am creating the object only on stack, I need not delete it. 
But what I thought was that it will automatically delete only the member variables including the pointers inside the class but I have to explicitly `free` the memory allocated for using `malloc` for `data` and `x`

So I wrote the Class's destructor as

```
Attributes::~Attributes()
{
if(data!=NULL)
    free(data);
if(x!=NULL)
    free(x);
}
```

As expected, once the scope of `attr` expires, the destructor is called. but on execution of `free` I get this error:

```
*** Error in '~/Plot':double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000002a7e9d0 ***
```

Can anyone explain me what is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` and `free` rather than `new` and `delete`?

Comment: @EdChum I thought I can use either of it in C/C++. Cant I?

Comment: BTW `free(NULL)` is valid, so the test is useless.

Comment: You can't, just shouldn't :) malloc/free is c, new/delete is c++. Both are pretty deprecated in "modern" c++, which means there are easier, safer ways to do this, like smart pointers: `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::weak_ptr`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Okay did not know that.thanks. but still it does not solve the problem.

Comment: I suspect that you do a copy of `Attributes`, and you don't respect the rule of three.

Comment: Btw. the malloc/new should happen in the constructor of the class, not "at some point in the main function", that's just bad engineering. What we see from your code seems to be fine. Are you sure there isn't some other frees, or copies of `attr`?

Comment: @Jonathan: see the second next line, `attr.data = data;`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter But I am assigning it to the class variable in the next step right?

Comment: @Zsolt I am sure there is only one instance of attr.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that bit. Carry on!

Comment: Post the whole program and we'll point out where the copies are

Comment: Maybe you `free` also in main somewhere?

Comment: @VivekVK Did you pass `attr` to any function by value. This will trigger the copy constructor and when leaving the function `data` , `x` values will be freed there.

Comment: Can not reproduce http://ideone.com/gQVB4s.

Comment: @VivekVK `I am sure there is only one instance of attr`  I bet there are more instances, ones you didn't create explicitly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes there were copies that I did not mean to create. Sorry for such a strong statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably copying `attr` somewhere.

Here is a (working, not fixing the issues others have mentioned in the comments) version of your question. It does not trigger any doublefree errors:

```
#include <cstdlib>

class Attributes
{
public:
    float* data;
    float* x;
    float min_x;
    float max_x;
    ~Attributes() {
      if(data!=NULL)
    free(data);
      if(x!=NULL)
    free(x);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int N = 100;
  Attributes attr;
  float* data =(float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
  float* x =(float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
  attr.data = data;
  attr.x = x;
}
```

The point is: when you are copying attr (even implicitly), you are responsible to either

- track the resource usage (two objects refering to the same memory)
- or also copy the allocated resources (i.e. depending on your specific semantics you can either set the pointers to NULL in the (copy-)constructor or you allocate a new array upon construction (which means you need to carry along a length field also, seriously, you should use std::vector)

You could use a smart pointer library to take care of your specific problem.

Comment: Why are you creating 100 floats? Why aren't you storing that size somewhere?

Comment: Because it does not matter for the sake of the memory management example. In an actual program of course, it does matter ;).

Comment: it was indeed a copy which I did not mean to do and that caused lot of problems. I leant something new. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::vector`, something like:

```
class Attributes
{
public:
    void resize(std::size_t size)
    {
       data.resize(size);
       x.resize(x);
    } 
private:
    std::vector<float> data;
    std::vector<float> x;
    float min_x;
    float max_x;
};
```

Comment: As N seems to be a compile-time constant, `std::unique_ptr<std::array<float, N>>` is a better fit.

Comment: If `N` is a compile time constant, `float data[N];` or `std::array<float, N> data;` are other options.

Comment: They are, but the data ends up in automatic memory, whereas OP's goal is to use dynamic memory (most probably because the arrays are potentially big).

Comment: @Quentin:So `std::unique_ptr<Attributes>` can be a complement. BTW, the overhead with `std::vector` over `std::unique_ptr<std::array<float, N>>` is negligible.

Comment: I'd hope so. That's probably an opinion thing, but I like to use `std::array` in these cases, because you can hardly mess it up (no `reserve()` to call, no tempting `push_back()` and surprise reallocation), and it doesn't convey the "this is a growable container" idea that a `std::vector` does. All of which would of course be solved by a thin wrapper, but hey, the functionality is there already, so why bother.

Comment: The reason I am not using vectors is because I will be calling legacy C libraries which take in only arrays with the data all the time and I will have to  convert vector into an array and send it to the function every time. I just thought I could avoid it.

Comment: @VivekVK: You may still use [`std::vector::data`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) to interface with C Librairies without overhead.